# python list comprehension and looping question

Tags: python

I have variables as follows:

```
J = range (1,16)

T = range (1,9)

x= {} # 0,1 decision variable to be determined
```

These variables turn into combinations of `x[j,t]`.

I am trying to implement a constraint for unacceptable `t` types in `T` for `x[j,t]` combinations that make the `x` var = 0.

I have a dictionary 'U' with `j`'s as the key and `t` types and values stored in a list. Zero value means t is unacceptable, 1 is acceptable. The index is range 1-9, not 0-8. So in the example below, j 2, type 3 (bc its at index 3 on range(1,9)) is the only acceptable value.

```
{1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 2: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 3: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 4: [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 5: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 6: [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 7: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 8: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 9: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 10: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 11: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 12: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 13: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 14: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 15: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
}
```

I am struggling in trying to get the x[j,t] combinations bc of the misaligned index. I set it up like so:

```
for j,t in x:
    if t in U[j]==0:
        # do the thing... #addConstr(x[j,t], GRB.EQUAL,0)
```

So for `j 2` the results I need are `{(2,1):0, (2,2):0, (2,4):0, (2,5):0, (2,6):0, (2,7):0, (2,8):0}` where the index value on range `(1,9)` becomes the `t` value in the tupledict.

Any pointers?  Thank you!

Comment: `range(1, 15)` ends at 14, not 15.

Comment: Yes, thanks I quickly plugged that in there-- it goes much higher. I changed the J range to (1,16) so that it reads correctly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example data is stored in `U`, what you want to do is:

```py
j_results = []
for j,types in U.items():
    results = {}
    for t in types:
        if t == 0.0:
            result[(j,int(t))] = 0
    j_results.append(result)
```

`j_results` list will contain all results like you described:

> for `j 2` the results I need are `{(2,1):0, (2,2):0, (2,4):0, (2,5):0, (2,6):0, (2,7):0, (2,8):0}`

will be in `j_result[1]` (counter intuitive because your U data start from 1)

Note the `int` cast, because data you provided has floats, but results you provided are a tuple of ints.